# Bandwith use of ros topic

Tags: ros, network, topic, bandwidth, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm going to run my ros system on multiple computers, connected only by a wifi link of (possibly) bad quality. However I want to use data from multiple usb web cams.

I'm wondering how ros distributes the various message on the network and if it makes a difference where roscore is located.

Example Scenario:

```
Machine 1:
  Node 1:
    outgoing topics:
      camera1/image_raw
      camera1/image_compressed

Machine 2:
  Node 2:
    outgoing topics:
      camera2/image_raw
      camera2/image_compressed

Machine 3:
  Node 3.1:
    incoming topics:
      camera1/image_raw
      camera2/image_raw
    outgoing topics:
      control/steering
      control/debug

  Node 3.1:
    incoming topics:
      camera1/image_raw
      control/steering
```

1. Which messages are actually send?
2. Do the camera*/image_compressed topics take up bandwith, even though they are never subscribed to?
3. is camera1/image_raw send twice over the network?
4. is camera2/image_raw also send to machine 1?
5. Does it matter whether roscore is started on machine 1 or machine 3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30624/bandwith-use-of-ros-topic/) by [NsN](https://answers.ros.org/users/1786/nsn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each message is sent pairwise over a TCP connection, directly from the publisher to each subscriber.

1. Messages that are actually subscribed
2. No.
3. Yes. I believe there are ways to avoid that.
4. No.
5. Mostly not.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-03-27**:
Re 3): You can use http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/relay on machine 3 to have a local node that republishes the incoming images, so that other local nodes can subscribe to that relay instead of the topic published by machine 1.